# Print the content of text area not working

Tags: php

php:

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit_']))
 {
    if(isset($_POST['textEditor']) && !empty($_POST['textEditor']))
    {
       echo 'hello';
       $msg = $_POST['textEditor'];
       echo ($msg);
    }
 }
```

html:

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit_" value="Add" />
 <textarea name="textEditor" rows="20" cols="60" > </textarea>
```

I want to print the content of the text area when submit button is clicked. But even when the textarea is non-empty, it prints nothing.

For testing, I printed 'hello', but it still prints nothing that is the **second ' if ' statement is not satisfied**. **I do not understand why does the second ' if ' statement fail** !

And if I remove the second if statement, then I get an error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: textEditor in...
```

Comment: Seems like your textarea is outside the form? Why would it be after the submit button? Probably you've also closed the form after the button on your real page.

Comment: please show your full html code with from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you have `texteditor` outside of form you need to try like

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_']))
 {
    if(isset($_POST['textEditor']) && !empty($_POST['textEditor']))
    {
       echo 'hello';
       $msg = $_POST['textEditor'];
       echo ($msg);
    }
 }
?>
<form method="post">
<textarea name="textEditor" rows="20" cols="60" > </textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit_" value="Add" />
</form>
```

if form is set already try to check form `method="post"` or `print_r($_POST);` in php code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_']))
 {
    if(isset($_POST['textEditor']) && !empty($_POST['textEditor']))
    {
       echo 'hello';
       $msg = $_POST['textEditor'];
       echo ($msg);
    }
 }
?>
<head>



</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" method="post">

        <textarea name="textEditor" rows="20" cols="60" > </textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_" value="Add" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Might be debugging the code will help you.
as put this code under if(isset($*POST['submit*'])) { line

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

hope this helps.